# abort() has been called on winsock recv() method

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm trying to receive messages from the server I'm building.

At a certain point, when the client has connected to the server, I start a receive thread which runs constantly.
I start is with this code:

```
std::thread receiveThread(&NetworkingLib::Base::Receive, this);
```

It is called from a method within the same class the Receive() method is in.

Now after that it does go into the Receive() method but it crashes when the recv() method is being called (the Winsock one).

```
if (ConnectSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    ...
}
```

All those variables contain a working value though.
The error says:

```
R6010 - abort() has been called.
```

I have no idea how to solve this or what might be the problem.

EDIT:

Here's some extra code to show how the socket was created and such. (I left out most of the error checking)

recvbuf and recvbuf are declared as follows:

```
int recvbuflen;
char recvbuf[512];
```

After that in the constructor, recvbuflen is declared as follows:

```
Base::Base(void):
     recvbuflen(512)
{
    ...
}
```

Here's how I created the socket object:

```
// Create a SOCKET to connect to the server
ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

// Connect to server.
iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
```

After this has been done I start the receive thread. (The first piece of code in this post)

Comment: The more complete sample is needed.

Comment: What do you need? The thing that gets called after the recv() method? I put a breakpoint at the recv() line and this is where it crashes.

Comment: How `ConnectSocket` is initialized? Where `recvbuf` and `recvbuflen` are placed? The code of listener thread?

Comment: I hope I added enough?

Comment: Seems like your object is got destroyed at the moment of `recv` call and you simply have access violation when `recv` tries to write something to your buffer. Where the instance of `Base` is created?

Comment: The instance is created in the main class of the application. Hmm... but if it were to be deleted, why does it hold a value which seems to be a "good" value according to the data I saw on the server from the socket used by the client? I also check if the socket object is not INVALID_SOCKET.

Comment: Can you just put the link to the whole client code?

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
receiveThread.detach();
```

after creating a thread. As it gets deleted on scope exit otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the method which created the receiveThread object returned which resulted in the receiveThread object getting destroyed. Because receiveThread is joinable, then when it is destroyed, it calls terminate() which gives you the error.

You have two options:

1. Call `receiveThread.detach()` severing this object to the thread thus making it non-joinable so when it is destroyed nothing bad happens.
2. If you want later to join the thread then allocate it on the heap with new - store its pointer somewhere so that later you can join it and then delete it.